# Shapefile layer no longer editable (toggle edit option greyed out) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, qgis-2

I am using QGIS 2.16 / Windows 10.

I have a point shapefile which I have been using for a little while that has always been editable.

Today I was editing the layer, saved my edits and left my computer for a few hours. When I came back I was not able to toggle the editing button on the toolbar and when I right click on the layer it longer has toggle editing as an option.

I have googled the problem every way I can think of and have not been able to find an answer to why the layer is suddenly un-editable or how to fix this.

Comment: is there an active query on the shapefile? have you tried restarting qgis? is the shapefile used by any other application?

Comment: What version QGIS? What OS? Did u use a Filter?

Comment: So, I don't have any active querries, I've restarted QGIS twice to no use and teh shapefile is only open in QGIS. The folder that holds it isn't even open in Windows explorer.

I'm using QGIS 2.16.0 on Windows 10, no filters. The only thing I have that affects the layer is a label by expression.

Comment: Shape local or network? If local, boot system to check if lock has disappeared. If network, might be another user / application. Really sounds like a locking issue to me. Could me the size as well. What is the size of the data? Components can have a max size. (2GB?).

Comment: So kid you not I just left my computer for half an hour, came back, right clicked on the layer and toggle editing is back. I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

Comment: Happy it works again. You didn't answer previous questions yet. Maybe it is a problem with locking / sleeping / stand-by of the system. I have simular problems with PostGIS layers  in QGIS when returning to work from lunch.

Comment: Sorry, the shape is local, size is tiny, 226kb.

If it locks again at any time today I'll try Bunny's answer and report back.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu with a polygon layer (editing, no problem, then suddenly the layer is not editable). None of the above suggestions have re-enabled editing for me. Has anyone found anything that helps?

Comment: Obviously you've tried closing and re-opening just the shapefile itself? This fixed the problem for me, when the full QGIS restart and Layer panel refresh failed.

Comment: Just a double check, are you in the correct Panel?
Because there is 'Layers Panel' (the correct one) and 'Layer Order Panel'(which is faded when bottom toggle option 'Control rendering order' is off)

Answer (score 8):

It happened the same to me. Sometimes QGIS (2.18.11) blocks the edition when you "save as..." your project.
Just remove the shp from the box and import it again. That should work. If not, save your layer as a new shp.

It also happens with duplicate layers.

Comment: Happened to me in QGIS 3 with a layer imported from a zipfile.  Unzipping the file before import solved it.

Comment: with me it was when loading it from a url. Downloading the file and opening again solved it

Comment: It also happened to me when connecting to PostGIS on QGIS 3.4. Simply removing and readding the layer back the map will solve this.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, and it was with a layer that was imported directly from a zipped folder.  After unzipping the original folder, and re-importing the shapefile from the unzipped folder, I was able to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Solution: Along the top menu, `Layer \ Save as`. This exports the layer, and creates a copy inserted above the existing layer in the Layers Panel. When I did this, the new copy was editable.

Answer (score 1):

This is one kind of Bug coming from 2.8.4 Version. some times it happens when you keep Double clicking on the layers . I have faced the same kind of issue. may be your issue can be resolved if you can Disable the Layers option and enable it again.

Try this way

after loading the shape files go to  View > Panels > Layers [ Disable/ Uncheck]

then go to the same place and enable the layers option.

I hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found that enabling snapping (Snapping Panel) and disabling the Enable snapping on intersections, restores editing function.

Answer (score 1):

I imported my point files as a delimininated text layer (originally) and was unable to edit. If you then save layer as a shapefile or export as a geopackage, this might help. It did for me but mine was originally a different file format

Answer (score 0):

Simply highlight the shp file and all it sub-files. Then right click and choose properties. Then uncheck the read-only, afterwards restart QGIS and you're all set.